# nebular menu parent active class not working

Tags: angular, angular6, nebular, angular6-json-schema-form

I am using nebular with Angular 6, facing an issue while clicking on menu item , active class on parent menu item not added.
but if you see the http://akveo.com/ngx-admin, while you click on ""buttons" inside "UI-features" them UI-features get highlighted.

Below is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Dashboards",
        "icon": "font_icons8 icons8-statistics",
        "link": "/dashboard",
        "home": true
    },
    {
        "title": "UI Features",
        "icon": "font_icons8 icons8-data-configuration",
        "link": "/ui-features",
        "children": [
            {
                "title": "Typography",
                "link": "/ui-features/typography"
            },
            {
                "title": "Grid",
                "link": "/ui-features/grid"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Please help me get rid of this issue.

Comment: Actually, No...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [Minimal Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue.

Comment: Hi SiddAjmera, I have tried to make sample but its not working but somehow tried to write code as per my application. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcmqs4. I hope it will help you to understand

Comment: @RakeshSingh did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

in the link property of every single menu item I set the full path of the Item.
Previously i was only setting the /componentName instead of the /fullpath/componentName

Answer (score 1):

Just set the **pathMath** prop of parent with **'prefix'** value and give him a link. After this, set a **pathMath** prop of children with **'full'** value.

See my sample works:

```
{
        title: 'Security',
        icon: 'lock-outline',
        link: '/security',
        pathMatch: 'prefix',
        children: [
          {
            title: 'User',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            link: '/security/user',
            selected: false,
          }]
}
```

Note: Your routes should be setted with exatcly link of your menu item, like this:

```
  {
    path: 'security/user',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/security/register-user/register-user.module').then(
        (m) => m.RegisterUserModule,
      ),
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved removing the "/" at the end of the link in the menu item.

Like this:

```
      {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'home-outline',
    link: '/home/',
    home: true,
  },
```

It doesn't turn blue, I solved with this:

```
      {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'home-outline',
    link: '/home',
    home: true,
  },
```

I know it's late, but maybe this can help someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works you can try this code.

```
{
title: "Dashboard",
icon: "people-outline",
link: "/dashboard"
 },
 {
title: "Calendar",
icon: "pie-chart-outline",
children: [
  {
    title: "Day-cell",
    link: "/day-cell"

  },

]
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments and by looking through the nebular source code, what I could find out was:

1. The link property of an `NbMenuItem` should be prefixed with `/`.
2. The `items` attribute that we pass to the `<nb-menu>` element should be initialized from the beginning.
   See the next paragraph to bypass this requirement. Details/reason for the above is: There is a [private method `setParent()`](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/8.0.x/src/framework/theme/components/menu/menu.service.ts#L359) that sets the `parent` attribute of each menu item's children, and this method is only called on `ngOnInit` of `NbMenuComponent`, so this component needs the menu items during the ngOnInit phase.

If initialising the menu items from the start is not an option, you need to set the `parent` property of each child by yourself.
Following `setParent` function takes an item and sets its children's parents.

```
    private setParent(item: NbMenuItem) {
        item.children && item.children.forEach(child => {
          child.parent = item;
          this.setParent(child);
        });
      }
```

Then call this `setParent` on all the elements of the `items` list i.e. `items.map(item => this.setParent(item))` where `items` is the list of nebular menu items.